# Replacing The Displayed URL When Sharing On Social Media

Tags: meta-tags, social-media

The best way I can explain this question is with a real life example.

Team Rock host their magazine Classic Rock as a subdomain to the comapny website, i.e. `http://classicrock.teamrock.com`, which is exactly what I want to do with my website and associated blogs.

The problem is that when you share a Classic Rock post on Facebook, it shows the Image/Title/Description for the selected article, but it displays `TEAMROCK.COM`, as shown below:

[image]

Is there any way of replacing the primary domain name with the name of the blog? And if so, does this work with ALL social network sites?

Comment: I'm new myself, but this question might be a fit for the webapplications.SX sub site

Answer (score 1):

What is being used is the OpenGraph protocol which was brought into being by Facebook to aid in passing rich content from a site being shared to the Facebook servers and to make webmasters have more control over how their pages are shared and displayed.

In this particular case the og:url meta is being used in the form of `<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/" />`. Even though this is being served from the sub domain Facebook see's the `og:url` tag and changes the URL being shown to the end user and the user being redirected to on click.

You can find more about the OpenGraph protocol from http://ogp.me.